# ¿Como borrar un registro de un archivo en C?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una práctica con archivos binarios en C, es una agenda de Contactos en la que se puede guardar, mostrar y eliminar contactos. Tengo hechas las funciones pero a la hora de borrar un contacto lo que hago es pedirle al usuario que introduzca el nombre del contacto a borrar y leo el archivo donde estan guardados los contactos y mientras hago eso voy escribiendo un archivo auxiliar los contactos menos el que tenga el nombre ingresado, luego de esto sobreescribo el archivo original por el auxiliar. Mi problema es que al hacer esto me borra todos los contactos en vez de solo el que ingrese.

```
        //Agenda
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #define NAME_ARCHIVE "contacts.bin"
        #define NAME_ARCHIVE_AUX "contacts_aux.bin"
        //Contactos
        typedef struct contacts{
            char name[20];
            char direcction[30];
            int phone;
        }Contacts;
        //Funciones
        void menu(char *nameArchive);
        Contacts createContact();
        void saveContact(Contacts contact, char *nameArchive);
        void showContacts(char *nameArchive);
        void deleteContact(char *nameArchive);
        void stop();

        int main (){

            menu(NAME_ARCHIVE);
            stop();
            return 0;
        }

        void menu(char *nameArchive)
        {
            int op;
            do{
                system("cls");
                printf("[1]Create contact\n");
                printf("[2]Show contacts\n");
                printf("[3]Delete contact\n");
                printf("[4]Exit\n");
                printf("Login option: ");
                scanf("%i",&op);
            if(op>0 && op<5){
                system("cls");
                switch(op){
                    case 1:
                        saveContact(createContact(),NAME_ARCHIVE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showContacts(NAME_ARCHIVE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        deleteContact(NAME_ARCHIVE);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        exit(1);
                    default:
                        printf("wrong choice\n");
                        stop();
                }
            }
            }while(op!=4);
        }
        //Creando el contacto
        Contacts createContact()
        {
            Contacts contact;
            printf("Name:\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(contact.name);
            printf("Direcction:\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(contact.direcction);
            printf("Phone number:\n");
            scanf("%i",&contact.phone);

            return contact;
        }

        void saveContact(Contacts contact, char* nameArchive)
        {
            FILE* file;
            //si el archivo existe va a
            //gregar el nuevo contacto que creamos al final del archivo
            //no va a sobreescribir
            file=fopen(nameArchive,"ab");

            if(!file){
                printf("Error\n");
                stop();
            }
            else{
                //Recibe 4 parametros:
                //1-Dirección de memoria de la variable que queremos guardar
                //2-El tamaño del tipo de dato
                //3-La cantidad de datos que queremos guardar
                //4-La variable del archivo
                fwrite(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, file);
                printf("Contact Save!\n");
                stop();
                fclose(file);
            }

        }

        void deleteContact(char *nameArchive)
        {
            system("cls");
            FILE *file, *fileAux;
            Contacts contact;
            fileAux=fopen(NAME_ARCHIVE_AUX,"wb");
            file=fopen(nameArchive,"rb");

            if(!file){
                printf("Empty\n");
            }
            else{

                char name[20];
                printf("Name of the contact to delete:\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(name);
                //Recibe los mismo parametros que fwrite
                while(fread(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, file)){

                    if (!strcmp(contact.name,name))
                    fwrite(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, fileAux);
                }
                fileAux=fopen(NAME_ARCHIVE_AUX,"rb");
                file=fopen(nameArchive,"wb");
                while(fread(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, fileAux)){

                    fwrite(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, file);
                }

            }

            stop();
            fclose(file);
            fclose(fileAux);
            remove(fileAux);
        }
        //Mostrar contactos
        void showContacts(char *nameArchive)
        {
            FILE *file;
            file=fopen(nameArchive,"rb");
            if(!file){
                printf("Empty\n");
                stop();
            }
            else{
                Contacts contact;
                printf("%-20s %-30s %-30s\n", "Name", "Direcction","Phone");
                //recibe los mismo parametros que fwrite
                while(fread(&contact, sizeof(Contacts),1, file)){
                    printf("%-20s %-30s %-30i\n", contact.name, contact.direcction,contact.phone);
                }
                fclose(file);
                printf("\n");
                stop();

            }
        }

        void stop()
        {
            printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
            getch();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que antes de volver a abrir los archivos tenés que cerrarlos, o sea agregar

```
fclose(fileAux); fclose(file);
```

antes de

```
fileAux=fopen(NAME_ARCHIVE_AUX,"rb");
file=fopen(nameArchive,"wb");
```

Comment: Ahora si funciona gracias, entonces tengo que cerrar para abrirlos de otro modo gracias